# Looking for assistance diagnosing SQL IndexOutOfRangeException & SQLException

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to return a list of customers with their associated products or associated payment types. I am able to return the customers by themselves, but not with either embedded/expanded information requests. I am rather new to coding, so the voluminous error messages do not mean much to me, as I don't know how to interpret them. I received the IndexOutOfRangeException : Product Id when trying to return the customer's products and a SQLException : Incorrect Syntax Near '.' for the payment types. I think I have named and referenced all the data fields and aliases properly, but I just can't find out what I'm overlooking.

Code for customers with products:

```
string command = "";

string customerColumns = @"
       SELECT c.Id AS 'CustomerId', 
       c.FirstName AS 'CustomerFirstName', 
       c.LastName AS 'CustomerLastName',
       c.AccountCreated AS 'DateJoined', 
       c.LastActive AS 'LastActive',
       c.Archived"; 

       string customerTable = "FROM Customer c";


if (include == "products")
  {
       string productColumns = @"
       pt.Name AS 'ProductType',
       p.Id,
       p.Title AS 'ProductName', 
       p.Description AS 'ProductDescription', 
       p.Price AS 'ProductPrice',
       p.Quantity AS 'QuantityAvailable',
       p.Archived";

       string productTables = @"
       JOIN Product p ON p.CustomerId = c.Id 
       JOIN ProductType pt ON pt.Id = p.ProductTypeId";

       command = $@"{customerColumns}, 
                 {productColumns} 
                 {customerTable} 
                 {productTables}";
   }

...

cmd.CommandText = command;
       SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
       List<Customer> Customers = new List<Customer>();

       while (reader.Read())
         {

         Customer currentCustomer = new Customer
           {
            Id = reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("CustomerId")),
            FirstName = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("CustomerFirstName")),
            LastName = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("CustomerLastName")),
            AccountCreated = reader.GetDateTime(reader.GetOrdinal("DateJoined")),
            LastActive = reader.GetDateTime(reader.GetOrdinal("LastActive")),
            Archived = reader.GetBoolean(reader.GetOrdinal("Archived"))
           };

         if (include == "products")

           {
            Product currentProduct = new Product
            {
             Id = reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("Id")),
             Title = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("ProductName")),
             Description = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("ProductDescription")),
             Quantity = reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("QuantityAvailable")),
             Price = reader.GetDouble(reader.GetOrdinal("ProductPrice"))
            };
```

Current code is shown above.

Anyone that can guide me or offer insight as to how to understand or figure out the error messages is greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: The IndexOutOfRangeException exception is telling you that the dataset that's executed and returned to your code does not contain a column named 'Product Id'.  I would suggest debugging your code, putting a breakpoint just before the point where you're sending the command to SQL Server.  Examine the finished command (string), and the query syntax issue should be more obvious.

Comment: ...also, avoid aliasing your columns using names that contain spaces.  Instead, use `CustomerId`, `CustomerFirstName`, etc.

Comment: I think you may be missing a preceding comma when you add additional columns.

Comment: I did remove the spaces from the aliasing, and added commas in the command string between the column arguments. The customers with payments is returning, but I am still getting the same error when querying for customers with products.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show what the code looks like now. Also, did you do what @Dbro suggests? Can you paste the string here?

Comment: Yes, I did remove the spaces from the aliasing. Current code is now shown in original post block. Thank you.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on this line `cmd.CommandText = command`, and debug.  When you hit the breakpoint, hover over `command` variable, copy the value, and paste back here.

Comment: When I do as you have said, I am only getting the customer table fields. For some reason, the productColumns and productTables argument are not being added to the command string, and I can't figure out why at this moment.